# TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /userers/../vendor/tcpdf/cache/img_8e7e19ef238db432ed8af1caa9ffe395

Tags: php, unix, tcpdf, php-7.2

I am setting up a new web app in my server by copying an existing one. But after copying the code the `TCPDF` throws an error.

*Note: The images are accessed using HTTPS from the same server*

I have tried changing the permission of cache folder to `777` but it didn't help.

> `TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /users/website1/apps/website1/releases/1567019143/web/app/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/vendor/tcpdf/cache/img_8e7e19ef238db432ed8af1caa9ffe395`